# ElectronNet build is missing needed files

Tags: electron, native, electron-builder

In electron.manifest.json, I have the following:

```
"extraResources": [
  {
    "from": "./bin",
    "to": "bin",
    "filter": ["**/*"]
  }
],
```

However, the electron build is missing a few needed files. These files came from a nugget package that the application is using and are located in the following folder:

`bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\runtimes\win7-x64\native`

I am wondering if it may be because these are windows specific files. The pipeline specifies a windows implementation. Here is the build command in azure-pipelines.yml (if it matters):

`electronize build /target win /package-json package.json /dotnet-configuration $(buildConfiguration)`

I have tried to specify the folder and the file several different ways (a few shown below), but I can’t get it to work.  There are only 3 missing DLLs so I don’t mind adding them individually if needed. And I can add the entire folder since there isn't anything else in the folder but the 3 DLLs.

Attempt 1 – adding a FROM folder:

```
"extraResources": [
  {
    "from": [ "./bin", "./bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/runtimes/win7-x64/native" ],
    "to": "bin",
    "filter": [ "**/*" ]
  }
],
```

Attempt 2 – specifying the file:

```
"extraResources": [
  {
    "from": [ "./bin", "./bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/runtimes/win7-x64/native/abcdef.dll" ],
    "to": "bin",
    "filter": [ "**/*" ]
  }
],
```

Attempt 3 – using a windows tag and a specific file:

```
"extraResources": [
  {
    "from": "./bin",
    "to": "bin",
    "filter": [ "**/*" ]
  }
],
"win": 
  {
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "./bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/runtimes/win7-x64/native/abcdef.dll",
        "to": "bin"
        "filter": [ "**/*" ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

How can I add DLL libraries to my electron build? And can I do that by passing in the build configuration (something like $(buildConfiguration))?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Andrew